# Text convert into other format in android

Tags: android

I get response from the server correctly. But when i display the it in android app it get convert into some other text.

**Please check below examples:**

**Balkánska 102** convert to **BalkÃ¡nska 102**

**OC Braník** convert to **OC BranÃ­k**

and lot of more

Thanks in advance to suggest for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is charset mismatch related issue. Enforce your remote server to send data in UTF8 or do convert what you get from server to UTF8 prior using in the app.

Comment: I did new String(xmlParser.getValue(element, "name").getBytes("UTF-8")) but still have same problem.

Comment: Check this I receive data from there http://www.bankomaty.sk/service/?n=26.874694&e=75.7837235&t=1.2.3.9

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are using the same encoding throughout the whole process. I can't say much else without some code examples.

Comment: I dint do encoding..What ever i receive from the server i just simply show it.but still having problemm